# How do I resolve a missing project subtype error I recieve when creating a new zebble project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I have installed Visual Studio Update 3, and I'm trying to work with the Zebble framework. I installed Xamarin, UWP, and other prerequisites. Still, I cannot create a new **Zebble for Xamarin - Cross platform solution** project.
I'm getting this error:

[image]

Would you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when you have an older version of UWP tools installed in your Visual Studio. You need to:

1. Edit Visual Studio to **uninstall** UWP tools.
2. Delete the old versions of UWP SDK from *Programs and Features*.
3. Close and restart your computer.
4. Edit Visual Studio to **install** UWP tools again.

[image]